# Why is hexcode output failing?

Tags: python, image, encryption-symmetric

```
from os import urandom
from PIL import Image
import io



for y in range((len(array2) -1), -1, -1):  
  decrypted_initial = decrypt(array2[y], key)
  if y > 0:
    decrypted_cipher = decrypt(decrypted_initial, array2[(y -1)])
  if y == 0:
    decrypted_cipher = decrypt(decrypted_initial, fixed_initialization_vector)
  immage_array.append(decrypted_cipher)
immage_array = [x for sets in immage_array for x in sets] #The list is all zeros since the image is all black.


for i in range(1000):
  print (immage_array[i]) #1000 zeroes printed.
if immage_array == myMessage: #Comparing the input hexocde for the encryption and output hexcode from the decryption.
    print("Yay.") #Print successful. 
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(bytes(immage_array))) #Not sure what this does exactly. I am just trying to get the hexcode to output as an image file.
image.save(output.png)
```

I am trying to do chain block cipher on an image and this is part of the code. I have been able to get the hex code of an image, encrypt it using chain block cipher, and decrypt it. I then compared the decrypted hex code with the original input hex code and I get a successful match. The hex code is returned as a list instead of a byte array though but the if statement still recognizes them as equal. I am having trouble converting the hexcode back into an image though.

I get this error. OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x039F1090>

The image is all black pixels for test purposes to make it easy to confirm the integrity of the hex code which I have confirmed to be identical to the input.

What is preventing me from turning the hexcode back into an image? I have tried looking everywhere for examples that worked but I have never been able to fully understand why it worked. Here is my logic.

immage_array is a list == (0, 0, 0, 0, ..., n)

bytes() #turns the immage_array list of all integers 0 into a byte array all consisting of x00.

io.BytesIO() A function needed for the byte array to be manipulated by the Image.open() function.

I then have the byte array stored as an object in the variable image.

image.save(output.png) The save function takes the filename as an argument. The image object is used.

I have honestly tried my hardest to find out where the logic is failing. I would appreciate an explanation of how to turn a list of (0, 0, 0, ..., n) into an image. Yes, I know, I have seen other examples of it being done on stack overflow. I am wondering why my implementation of it is failing.

Comment: It might help if you tell us which Image class you are using

Comment: The bytes.IO object needs to be the contents of a properly formatted image file. Not sure what you are creating your immage_array array from, but it doesn't look like it is the contents of an image. Are you sure you don't mean the `PIL.Image.frombytes` constructor?

Comment: I took the hexcode of an image file using myMessage = list(Image.open('myfile.png', 'r').getdata()), I then passed it through a chain block cipher algorithm I wrote myself and got the original list back. I used the if statement to compare them.

Comment: I see! Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just re-read your question. You cannot do this if your immage_array is [0, 0, 0...]. That is not an image, it is a bitmap (subtle difference). Use the PIL.Image.frombytes constructor.

If you want to encrypt images, just encrypt the whole contents, rather than extracting the file contents, converting it to a bitmap, then encrypting/decrypting it. When you convert it to a bitmap, for starters, it will be an order of magnitude more data, and secondly you loose the information on what format the image is (RGB, ARGB, monochrome, etc.)

As you have now disclosed, you are using the `PIL.Image.getdata` method. This returns a one-dimensional list, so how are you going to know the width/height at the other end? i.e. if your image is 640x480, from the other end you can't tell if it will be 480x640 or even 307200x1

Comment: This explains a lot. I got a college assignment to encrypt an image with my own chain block cipher algorithm and decrypt it. How would I break up an image file for chain block cipher if me getting the raw hexcode with PIL.Image.getdata is not feasible? I broke up the hex code into equal lengths of 6. I xor each block with an initialization vector and then a randomly generated key. Each previous block has to be used as the initialization vector.

Comment: Just read the bytes from the file using the `open` built-in function

Comment: It ended up working perfectly. I was surprised nearly all my code worked properly after getting the data with the open method. I am proud of all the work I put into this project. I did not really know anything about images except that there was 3 hexcode values for each pixel and I thought I needed just that. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: No problem! If you can accept and upvote my answer, hopefully someone else might find it useful to them in the future as well.